# Add cancel hyperlink to apply now popup in jobs

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Just as the "ask company x a question" hyperlink that brings up a popup allowing you to **cancel** the form, please add the **cancel** hyperlink in the **apply now** popup.

I know you can escape out of the dialog's but many don't and it just is cleaner to be consistent with the other popups.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this - we're adding it to our queue and should have a fix soon.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An enhancement is going out now. Thanks again.

Comment: I see this but the consistency is not there. The cancel in one pop up starts with upper case C the other is lower case. send message is all in lower case for asking a company a question whilst Submit is upper case for applying for a job.